# Which activity handles Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I've been digging for awhile into the source of the [Contacts app](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree) on Android to find out which Activity handles `Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED`. Unfortunately, I couldn't find its source code. Does anyone know how it's called, or even better where I can find it's source? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oddly enough, the [Phone application](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_phone/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) handles call-related events. ;)

You can watch `ActivityManager` output in logcat to see which component handles a particular `Intent`.

From the Contacts source code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED,
    Uri.fromParts("tel", number, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can reproduce this `Intent` on the command line:
`adb -e shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED -d tel:12345`

Which results in the following (nicely-formatted) logcat output:

```
Starting activity: Intent { 
    act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED 
    dat=tel:12345
    flg=0x10000000
    cmp=com.android.phone/.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster
}
```

This shows you that the `com.android.phone` application handles this particular `Intent`.

Comment: Huh nice one! It seems that what I'm after is called OutgoingCallBroadcaster. :)

Comment: can you tell me in which SDK version you find Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED? I cannot find it, even with syntax doesn't show it. Only see Intent.ACTION_CALL (sdk 2.1). thanks

Comment: It's a hidden API constant (using the @hide annotation).

Comment: @Christopher @Mathias Lin: And it is hidden because 3rd party apps are not allowed to make a call directly, they have to use the ACTION_CALL intent which displays the phone app dialer with the provided number, and waits for the user to confirm dialling the number.

Comment: @bjarkef: Apps can directly cause calls to occur; that's what `ACTION_CALL` does. What you just described is `ACTION_DIAL`.

Comment: I must use Intent.ACTION_CALL_PRIVELEGED. can someone please dictate me how to use @hide annotation? (what I understand ACTION_CALL: calls directly, ACTION_DIAL: opens the dialer, ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED shows a Activity chooser menu)