# Phone call application

Tags: android, phone-call, telephony

I am trying to create application, which sould work this way:

1. User dial a phone number (in contact or by dialer)
2. App will take the number send it to server
3. Server calls to the user
4. User answers the call
5. Server calls to the number

I have one problem. I cant handle the Intent from Dailer, using this `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="CallProgressActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch an outgoing call please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268763/how-to-use-android-intent-action-call-privileged-and-android-intent-action-new-o)

and also
[this](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151)

For auto-answering a call please check.

[this](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java)