# Can not resolve this CALL_PRIVILEGED permission

Tags: android

**SOLVED:**
Sry but I am an idiot. I forgot to make this import: `import android.Manifest`

I just want to check if the user has given the permission for making phone calls.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
   Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
}
```

Android Studio says that it can not resolve this `CALL_PHONE` symbol.

This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Can anybody help me?

EDIT:

My main problem is that I can`t read any permission at all.

Comment: Are you importing the correct Manifest class?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Since you cannot hold `CALL_PRIVILEGED`, and since the user cannot grant it to you, you have bigger problems. `CALL_PRIVILEGED` has a `protectionLevel` of `signature`. The only way an app can hold it is if the app is signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware, which means the app is part of some custom ROM. The user cannot grant you this permission. The user *can* grant you `CALL_PHONE`, and that is what you have in your manifest. Change your Java to refer to `CALL_PHONE`.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "I can't read any permission at all" means. Do you have an `import` statement for `Manifest.permission`?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes this was my problem thx =)

Comment: Write your solution as answer it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `Manifest.permission` constants, you need to `import android.Manifest`, as [`Manifest` is a Java class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

EDIT:

Check this post about [CALL_PRIVILEGED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268763/how-to-use-android-intent-action-call-privileged-and-android-intent-action-new-o)

Ok the permission exists but someone in this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10344) states that:

> This permission has the signatureOrSystem protection level, which is why it does not work, unless a user on a rooted phone makes the app a system app.

Comment: How does this fix the problem of that other permission not being resolved?

Comment: @Dominic What does not work? It does not compile? I see it fine in Android Studio.

Comment: Error:(132, 80) error: cannot find symbol variable CALL_PRIVILEGED

Comment: @Dominic: Get rid of all `CALL_PRIVILEGED` references from your code.

Comment: Of course its a permission https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html